# Reset button state after returning from jquery function

Tags: jquery, button

Is there a way of getting a button to reset to its default state after returning from a function? (I'm using bootstrap 3). I tried `$(this).unbind("mouseenter mouseleave");` but the button still doesn't revert to its unclicked state.

Here is a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Ld13o9no/1/

If you click the button you will see what I mean, you have to click outside the button for the (hover?) to go away.

Comment: provide a **runnable** [mcve]

Comment: think i revised it well enough now ;) thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you mean this?

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="batch-publish" class="btn btn-default">Test me</a>

$('#batch-publish').click(function (e) {

            $(this).blur();
            e.preventDefault();

    });
```